# Determining Total Assets, Total Liabilities From a Financial Statement with Missing Values

Tags: finance

I at a loss trying to figure out the total assets and liabilities from what is given.

```
                        K-Os Corporation
```

Beginning of year
    Total assets                   $66,410
    Total liabilities                  31,080 
    Total shareholders’ equity          35,330 
End of year       
    Total assets                   $[1]
    Total liabilities                       65,090
    Total shareholders’ equity                [9]
Changes during year in shareholders’ equity
    Issue of shares                     4,130
    Dividends                              13,640
    Total revenues                     54,610
    Total expenses                     40,410

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Remember the formula: *assets = liabilities + equity*

Then note you have been given four items that change equity.  So you need to figure out the sign of the change for each of the four items to get equity, and then apply the formula to get assets.

Comment: If it would be safe to assume that the 4 you are referring to are issue of shares, dividends, total revenues and total expenses, than  I would assume that you add issue of shares, dividends and total revenues and minues that from total expenses to get the sum of **$31,970"* for equity making total assets **$97,060*, would I be on the right track?

Comment: Almost, but one of those 3 you cite as inflows is an outflow.  Do you see which one?

Comment: Would it be dividends? (I'd assume this because they are not calculated into total equity on the financial position statement)

Comment: I think we have a winner!

Comment: Ahh, thanks so much for the help! It shed a ton of light on how to play around with financial statements.